# how to Validate Picker in xamarin forms using Behavior?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

using xamarin forms & PCL.

i want to validate the Picker using the Behavior to ensure that user picked an item from the Picker.

my behavior class is

```
public class PickerValidationBehaviour :Behavior<Picker>
{
    private Picker _associatedObject;
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }

    protected override void OnAttachedTo(Picker bindable)
    {
        base.OnAttachedTo(bindable);
        _associatedObject = bindable;
        if (_associatedObject.SelectedIndex < 0 )
        {
            HandleValidation();
        }
    }

    private void HandleValidation()
    {

    }

    private void _associatedObject_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected override void OnDetachingFrom(Picker bindable)
    {
        base.OnDetachingFrom(bindable);
        _associatedObject = null;
    }
}
}
```

and i was stuck because i want execute the validation before user action, such that the submit button will be hidden until the user fill the form.

and beside if there is any easy efficient way that i can perform the validation please mention it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this scenario you should put logic in VM instead of using behavior.

Cause behavior can change some UI element, like color something and most of them are the element itself's property.

In your case, you want to change another element in Page. There is a problem, how to access another element in your page.

If you binding SelectedIndex in you VM, and when property changed you can raise another property which controls the submit button. That will be easier then do it in behavior.